# What becomes of SIEM when a large database like teradata gets involved?

Tags: databases, siem

My topic sentence says it all.

I want to know the effect on performance, storage and analysis capabilities when teradata database is added. I'm talking about 70TB of storage with internal instructions processing per second close to 20 trillion bytes / second.

Also, the number of matches made on DB is of magnitude 20 million per second.

A middleware (e.d DAB) tool like infosphere guardium would help in performing log analysis and ease correlation efforts.

I'm more concerned with sizing issues.How much storage such a solution would require? Considering we are logging all (all critical events,select,insert,delete queries on all tables).

I just want general debate no perfect solution.  Thanks

Comment: Up until that last comment you were fine. The site is mostly for answers, not debates. ;)

Comment: So this question i going to be killed just on merits:). I'm sure with these big enough numbers a direct solution would not so easy. I prefer debate because this usually leads to answers. But if you have a solution for this case i love to hear it.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with security. Closed.

Comment: What about siem? It has nothing to do with SIEM to? What defines security by stackexchange begins to be quiet debatable. Actually i'm seeing this more often now;the community inability to answer tough questions is rounded up by insecure mods who just wants a forum with 0 unanswered questions make it look all dandy. Its funny. It really is.Thanks Rory.

Comment: @user970533 - All you want to do is debate.  This isn't a good question on this website.